# adding a hyperlink in one note to a document in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, onenote

We have a shared one note in a work space as well as a document library. I would like to add a hyperlink to documents in onenote with a link that works for all who have access to the onenote.

If I just drag an drop from the document library out of explorer it is a "personal" link.
It only work if I copy the link within the library after sharing the document. This requires several unecessary stept.

What is the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

The files you store on a SharePoint site are usually available to everyone with permissions to the site, but you may want to share specific files or folders with people who don't otherwise have access to the site. When you share files and folders, you can decide whether to let people edit or just view them.

Options for **Who would you like this link** to work for (options vary based on admin settings):

**Anyone** gives access to anyone who receives this link, whether they receive it directly from you or forwarded from someone else. This may include people outside of your organization.

Note: This option is not available in SharePoint Server 2019.

**People in**  gives anyone in your organization who has the link access to the file, whether they receive it directly from you or forwarded from someone else.

**People with existing access** can be used by people who already have access to the document or folder. Use this if you just want to send a link to somebody who already has access.

**Specific people** gives access only to the people you specify, although other people may already have access. If people forward the sharing invitation, only people who already have access to the item will be able to use the link.

For more information you could refer to:
[Share SharePoint files or folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-sharepoint-files-or-folders-1fe37332-0f9a-4719-970e-d2578da4941c)